# Hide and display DIV's depending on matching class and content

Tags: javascript

I am trying to hide or display a div depending on whether it has a matching class with the content.

In this example the class called 'Countries' contains the text 'USA'. I would like to display the 'search-result' div if has 'USA' in the class called 'Country'.

Here is my attempt. It hides the div 'Country' if I remove this

```
document.querySelectorAll(".search-result").forEach((z) => {
```

and change ? (z.style.display = "block")
: (z.style.display = "none");

to y.style.display

but I need to hide the overall div.

Can anyone help please?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style></style>
    <script src="https://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Countries">USA</div>

    <div class="search-result">
      <div class="Country d-none">USA, Canada, Bolivia, Paraguay</div>
      <div>The body of the result</div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-result">
      <div class="Country d-none">USA, Canada, Bolivia, Paraguay</div>
      <div>The body of the result</div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-result">
      <div class="Country d-none">Canada, Bolivia, Paraguay</div>
      <div>The body of the result - you should not see this one</div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-result">
      <div class="Country d-none">USA, Canada, Bolivia, Paraguay</div>
      <div>The body of the result</div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-result">
      <div class="Country d-none">Canada, Bolivia, Paraguay</div>
      <div>The body of the result - you should not see this one</div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.querySelectorAll(".Countries").forEach((x) => {
        document.querySelectorAll(".Country").forEach((y) => {
          document.querySelectorAll(".search-result").forEach((z) => {
            y.innerText.includes(x.innerText)
              ? (z.style.display = "block")
              : (z.style.display = "none");
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is called plural `<div class="Countries">USA</div>` but you only have a single country inside of it?

Comment: Why is the string `"USA"` inside a DIV and not a Search input value or a variable in JS?

Comment: Since you have "USA" right there hardcoded in HTML, why are your results not already filtered by the same backend that wrote that "USA" in .Countries?

Comment: Why .Countries and the .search-result do not have a common parent for reference? When you do `querySelectorAll(".searh-result")` you might get *any* `.search-result` in the document - not necessarily the one rreferencing USA

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. I changed the class names for privacy and I would agree they don't make much sense however the required logic remains. I can add the info for 'Country' anywhere in each div.  The data is pulled in via a JSON file and I don't want to hard code any data into the JS. None of the data is hardcoded IRL. It can change to any country name in the 'Countries' div depending on the page. This will be on multiple pages for different 'Countries'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already use the className `d-none` don't use `z.style.display = "none|block"`
**Use instead** `z.classList.toggle("d-none", !isMatch)`   where `isMatch` is a boolean value given the text was found. Use [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for that matter.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Example:

```js
// UTILITY functions

const EL = (sel, PAR) => (PAR||document).querySelector(sel); 
const ELS = (sel, PAR) => (PAR||document).querySelectorAll(sel); 
const trimLCase = (str) => str.trim().toLowerCase(); 

// APP

const EL_search = EL("#search");
const filterResults = () => {

  // Get the search value
  const search = trimLCase(EL_search.value);
  
  // Filter search results!
  ELS(".search-result").forEach(EL_result => {
    const EL_country = EL(".Country", EL_result);
    const content = trimLCase(EL_country.textContent);
    const isMatch = content.includes(search);
    EL_result.classList.toggle("d-none", !isMatch);
  });
};


// INIT, EVENTS

EL_search.addEventListener("input", filterResults);
filterResults();
```

```css
/* Utility classes */

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Search: <input id="search" value="USA" type=search autocomplete=off>

<div class="search-result">
  <div class="Country d-none">USA, Canada, Bolivia, Paraguay</div>
  <div>1. The body of the result U,C,B,P</div>
</div>
<div class="search-result">
  <div class="Country d-none">USA, Canada, Paraguay</div>
  <div>2. The body of the result U,C,P</div>
</div>
<div class="search-result">
  <div class="Country d-none">Canada, Bolivia, Paraguay, Guatemala</div>
  <div>3. The body of the result C,B,P,G</div>
</div>
<div class="search-result">
  <div class="Country d-none">USA, Paraguay, Guatemala</div>
  <div>4. The body of the result U,P,G</div>
</div>
<div class="search-result">
  <div class="Country d-none">Bolivia, Paraguay</div>
  <div>5. The body of the result B,P</div>
</div>
```

Above, since I used an `<input>` for demo, instead of

```js
const search = EL_search.value.trim().toLowerCase();
```

for your specific case you might want to use:

```js
const search = EL(".Country").textContent.trim().toLowerCase();
```

but it makes no sense to go for some Class Elements like `.Country` since it could later during development lead to false positives.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <style></style>
        <script src="https://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="Countries">USA</div>
    
        <div class="search-result">
          <div class="Country d-none">USA, Canada, Bolivia, Paraguay</div>
          <div>The body of the result</div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-result">
          <div class="Country d-none">USA, Canada, Bolivia, Paraguay</div>
          <div>The body of the result</div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-result">
          <div class="Country d-none">Canada, Bolivia, Paraguay</div>
          <div>The body of the result - you should not see this one</div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-result">
          <div class="Country d-none">USA, Canada, Bolivia, Paraguay</div>
          <div>The body of the result</div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-result">
          <div class="Country d-none">Canada, Bolivia, Paraguay</div>
          <div>The body of the result - you should not see this one</div>
        </div>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">

const countries = document.querySelector(".Countries");

const searchResults = document.querySelectorAll(".search-result");

for(let i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
    if(countries.innerText !== searchResults[i].innerText) {
        searchResults[i].parentNode.style.display = "none"
    } else {
        searchResults[i].parentNode.style.display = "block"
    }
}

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```